# adding jquery to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Where exactly do you add jquery code to rails 3.1.3? New to rails and I want to use masonry.js /http://masonry.desandro.com/ to my rails app.

I added jquery.masonry.min.js to app/assets/javascript and put //= require jquery.masonry.min in application.js but not sure where to put the masonry javascript code below. I thought it would go in the application.js but there is a comment that says it's not recommended to put code there. Any help?

```
$(function(){
  $('#container').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector : '.item',
    columnWidth : 240
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails is just trying to encourage you to keep your javascript organized, so that the main javascript file doesn't get massive and messy. You can put it in `application.js` while you are playing around and then move it to a page-specific javascript file later if you want, it won't actually hurt anything.

Rails will automatically make you an empty javascript file for each model, so if know you'll be using this in a model called `posts`, you would put it in `app/assets/javacsripts/posts.js`.

More on how the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) works here.